# Is there a way to get image focus values with new camerax?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camerax

I need to get as much values I can get from every image taken. start with the focus and focus distance. How can I get it from camerax?

I tried camera2 api and the focus distance is somehow always the same in every capture.

```
float lensFocusDistance = result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
float lensFocalLength = result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH);
float lensAperature = result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_APERTURE);
Pair<Float, Float> lensFocusRange = result.get(CaptureResult.LENS_FOCUS_RANGE);
```